# Replace multiple Character between two characters using sed or perl

Tags: perl, sed

I want to replace character e.g. ',' with ';' only between two consecutive  '[' and ']' using sed or perl linux command.

**Input**

```
abcd,e%sa,@ert&,,qet|,[,,efeg,sy bh|slhg],oiuy#,[abh,ohg;,a oiu],ayba
```

**Ouptut**

```
abcd,e%sa,@ert&,,qet|,[;;efeg;sy bh|slhg],oiuy#,[abh;ohg;;a oiu],ayba
```

I tried to create sed substitution command

```
echo "abcd,e%sa,@ert&,,qet|,[,,efeg,sy bh|slhg],oiuy#,[abh,ohg;,a oiu],ayba" | sed 's/\[\([^]]*\),\([^[]*\)\]/\[\1;\2\]/g'
```

Output

```
abcd,e%sa,@ert&,,qet|,[,,efeg;sy bh|slhg],oiuy#,[abh,ohg;;a oiu],ayba
```

but it is replacing only once in sub-string between each '[' and ']'.

What mistake I'm doing in the above sed command or any other way to do the same?

Comment: What is the expected output if the input is `[,[]` ?. Notice that the `,` is between two consecutive `[` and `]`. In other words, what should the output be in case that the brackets are unbalanced? Or, or even they are balanced such as `[,[]]` ?

Answer (score 3):

Using `Perl`, you could use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[^],]*\K,
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/FV6jof/1/).

---

In `Perl` this could be:

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/(?:\G(?!\A)|\[)[^],]*\K,/;/g' test.txt
```

Comment: I don't have much idea on perl scripting. Can you elaborate how to use the above expression with perl command?

Answer (score 3):

I know you said you wanted sed or perl but the code to do this would be very clear and simple in GNU awk:

```
$ awk -v RS='[[][^]]+]' '{gsub(/,/,";",RT); printf "%s%s", $0, RT}' file
abcd,e%sa,@ert&,,qet|,[;;efeg;sy bh|slhg],oiuy#,[abh;ohg;;a oiu],ayba
```

In the above you just set `RS` to the regexp you want to find (`[` then not `]`s then `]`), then replace `,` with `;` within the strings that match that regexp (as stored in `RT`) and then print the result. No cryptic escape sequences or arcane combinations of single character runes required.

I expect a sed script that can do this will be GNU-specific, and perl is non-standard so if you have or can install either of those then you should have or be able to install GNU awk too.

Answer (score 2):

Modified sample input, hope my understanding of the question is correct:

```
$ s='a,b,c[,,1,23,4]e,w[6,7,,32]j,g'

$ echo "$s" | sed ':a s/\[\([^]]*\),\([^[]*\)\]/\[\1;\2\]/; ta'
a,b,c[;;1;23;4]e,w[6;7;;32]j,g
```

The `sed` command above is modified from the one mentioned in the question to use a loop to replace all occurrences. You can simplify it to `sed -E ':a s/(\[[^]]*),([^[]*])/\1;\2/; ta'`

`:a` marks a label for the substitute command. `ta` will branch to label `a` only if the substitution succeeds. See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Programming-Commands for documentation.

You can do it without loop using `perl`

```
$ echo "$s" | perl -pe 's/\[[^]]+]/$&=~tr|,|;|r/ge'
a,b,c[;;1;23;4]e,w[6;7;;32]j,g
```

The `e` flag allows to use Perl code in replacement section. Here `$&=~tr|,|;|r` will replace `,` with `;` only for the matched portion (`$&` is similar to `&` in `sed` - gives entire matching portion)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. sed works in my system, but somehow with the perl command I'm getting following error.
$ echo "$s" | perl -pe 's/\[[^]]+]/$&=~tr|,|;|r/ge'
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "tr|,|;|r"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "tr|,|;|r "
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @rohitsoren not sure about the error, I just checked again and it works for me. `perl --version` gives me `v5.22.1`, what's yours?

Comment: @Sundeep my perl version is v5.8.8. Your sed solution worked for me.

Comment: @EdMorton sed variant - GNU sed version 4.1.5